# Check if a class exists within a method

Tags: plugins, php, oop

I'm new to OOP and I'm writing my first plugin. I want to check if the [Facebook plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/facebook/) has already been activated. If so, I want to skip some code:

```
class MyClass {
...
    function fb_js_sdk_setup() {
        // Check if Facebook plugin is activated 
        if ( class_exists( 'Facebook_WP' ) )
            return;
        // Continue if Facebook plugin is not active
        ...
    }

}
```

My `if (class_exists())` statement isn't working. Appreciate any advice and pointers. Thanks!

Comment: On which action do your create your instance? Make sure to wait until the Facebook plugin has started.

Comment: @toscho oh, good point. My instance is attached to `init` which I guess is too early. When should I load it instead?

Comment: `wp_loaded` maybe? I don’t know when the FB instance is created. Darshan’s advice is good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [`is_plugin_active()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_plugin_active) method to check if a certain plugin is activated. The class `Facebook_WP` will still exists even you deactivate the plugin.